# Twitter Bootstrap Modal not popping up for user login

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, modal-dialog

I'm having trouble incorporating a twitter bootstrap pop-over modal with devise login/signup for when a user lands on our home page. I've spent some time implementing different methods but still no success. As of right now, when I click on the "login" button that is associated with the modal, the site refreshes but there is no modal.

apps/views/layout/_header.html.slim (my application.erb file calls in other partials)

```
li
  = link_to "Login", "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#login_modal", :class => "btn btn-small"

li
  = link_to "Sign Up Free", "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#sign_up_modal", :class => "btn btn-small"
```

I have two partials (sign_up_modal, login_modal) that are almost identical...

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="sign_up">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
</div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
    <div>
        <%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <p>
            <div>
                <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'btn btn-small btn-success' %>
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-small" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </p>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

In my application.coffee I've made sure to require twitter/bootstrap

```
#= require twitter/bootstrap
```

And I've made sure to add the gem to my gemfile

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

When I click on either "sign up" or "login" the page just refreshes..I believe I've added all my code, sorry new to stack overflow!

apps/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new

end

def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_path
end

def destroy
 session[:user_id] = nil
 redirect_to root_path
end

end
```

Comment: show me the link to sign up and login modal. I am sure the link is wrong

Comment: the links to the sign up and login modal are at the top of my code above

Comment: sorry, editing my code right now, thought they were up there but i pasted the wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this on the button that is supposed to trigger the modal

```
<%= link_to "login", new_user_session_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#your_modal_id', :class => "btn btn-primary", :method: 'get' %>
```

For this to work you will have to overwrite devise `sessions #new` and `registrations #new` to respond to ajax requests. you can do this by introducing a respond_to block on both of these actions like this

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

then in your `app/views/devise/registrations` and `app/views/devise/sessions` create `new.js.erb` files. You can remove the login and sign-up forms from the modal and put the javascript to render the forms inside the modals in these `new.js.erb` files.

You can remove the form from the modal and in `modal-body` you put a loading gif. You can instead put the form in a partial and place it in `app/views/devise/sessions/_login_form.html.erb`. Then in `app/views/devise/sessions/new.js.erb` you do something like this.

```
$('#your_modal_id').remove-data
$('.modal-header').html ("<%= escape_javascript(render'/path/to/partial/with/header/content') %>");
$('.modal-body').html ("<%= escape_javascript(render '/path/to/partial')) %>");
$('.modal-footer').html ("<%= escape_javascript(render '/path/to/partial')) %>");
```

Comment: Sorry i failed to mention for this to work you have to overwrite the `:new` action of devise `SessionsController` and make it respond to ajax requests.

Comment: Would you possibly be able to edit your response with that information? I'm confused.

Comment: I've updated my questions with my current sessions_controller.rb that I created. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer but now I'm lost on what I need to put in the new.js.erb file, I thought all the JS was handled by twitter bootstrap?

Comment: This is not working. Not sure why but still getting the same response.

Comment: @milehighcoder One more thing i've noticed in your question is that your SessionController subclasses ApplicationController instead of Devise::SessionsController.

Comment: I've changed this to use the SessionController that is installed when using the devise gem. So I edited the new method in that controller to respond to JS there...still not working.

Comment: @milehighcoder if it is still refreshing the page then it is not performing and ajax request, do you have `:remote => true` as an option in your `link_to`

Comment: yes, i copied exactly what you had posted and changed the id to my modal id

Comment: did anyone get an answer that works with this? I can't follow the instructions from the point that it suggests creating new.js.erb files.