# Twitter Bootstrap Modals not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've been trying to set up twitter bootstrap modals for my devise and omniauth logins with no success. I've tried following several tutorials as well and still can't get them to open.

I'm not getting an error in my server logs, just the following:

```
"Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as JS"
```

I've required twitter/bootstrap in my application.coffee file

```
#= require_self
#= require twitter/bootstrap
#= require ./util
#= require ./home and so on
```

In my application.html.slim I've added two additional links to sign in/login next to the existing ones just to make sure these work before deleting the old ones

```
li
  = link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#login_modal', :class => "btn btn-small", :method => 'get'

li
  = link_to "Sign Up Free", new_user_session_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#sign_up_modal', :class => "btn btn-small", :method => 'get'
```

and then i have my sign_up_modal and login_modal which are both almost identical.

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="sign_up_modal">
<div class="modal-header">
<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div>
<%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <p>
    <div>
      <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'btn btn-small btn-success' %>
    </div>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-small" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
  </p>
   </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Modal not popping up for user login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348877/twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-popping-up-for-user-login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For "Login" link as shown below to work,**

```
li
  = link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#login_modal', :class => "btn btn-small", :method => 'get'
```

You will need to have `id = login_modal` of your `div` (enclosing the Login form)
For example:

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="login_modal">
```

**For "Sign Up Free" link as shown below to work,**

```
li
  = link_to "Sign Up Free", new_user_session_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#sign_up_modal', :class => "btn btn-small", :method => 'get'
```

You will need to have `id = sign_up_modal` of your `div` (enclosing the Sign Up form)
For example:

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="sign_up_modal">
```

Comment: I have both IDs correct already, just accidentally copied my old cover over for that section

Comment: So, are they matching EXACTLY as I suggested in answer?? Notice for sign up page the `id` should be `sign_up_modal` and NOT `sign_up`. Also, for login page `id` should be `login_modal` and NOT `login`.

Comment: Also, I recommend to update your question with **Correct** details otherwise it will be waste of time for the answerers, just the way I did it by answering on your incorrect code.

Comment: That was the ONLY issue in my code that I posted. The IDs are correct, I do not want to waste your time or mine :)

Comment: Then why don't you update your question accordingly. Else other users would give the similar answer that I gave looking at your code. As they might miss your comments on my answer.