# Devise Rails Bootstrap - sign up modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm trying to use a modal for my Rails Devise Bootstrap sign in & sign up forms.

I have tried to alter the link in views/devise/shared/registration_items to:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path, data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal") %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

I get a syntax error in the 'link_to(Register...' line.  Please can someone show me how to make these forms work with bootstrap modals.

Here is my registration_new view if it helps:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign up</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
           <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
             <%= f.error_notification %>

             <div class="form-inputs">
               <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
               <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
               <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
               <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
               <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>


                  </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-actions">
              <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a comma:

```
<%= link_to('Register', new_user_registration_path, data-toggle="modal", data-target="#myModal") %>
```

Also you should make extra parameters a hash, or better this:

```
<%= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#myModal" %>
```

Should work. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348877/twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-popping-up-for-user-login)

Comment: Hey Zishe, Thanks for the help. I edited the link line but now get a syntax error (unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end) - its referring to my 'registration_items' file. I'll keep looking, but thanks for the tip. I'm ticking your answer in the hope that it helps others with this part of the problem. <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#myModal") %>
    </li>
<% end %>

Comment: which one? after modal?

Comment: Ah, you mean bracket. Yes. I did that but now when I click on the link to 'Register' in my navbar, nothing happens. I click it and it doesn't show the modal.

Comment: Perhaps you should add like `, :remote => true` or define a method `, :method: 'get'`, which was in link.