# Devise sign up form with Rails & Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am trying (and failing) to get Rails Bootstrap and Devise to work so that my sign up form works in a Bootstrap modal.

I have configured the view so that it fits inside the modal window however, when I click on the navbar link to 'register' - the page refreshes but nothing happens. I was trying to follow these instructions, but I can't understand them from the point that they suggest creating new.js.erb files.

[Twitter Bootstrap Modal not popping up for user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348877/twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-popping-up-for-user-login)

I have as follows:

`views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign up</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
           <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
             <%= f.error_notification %>

             <div class="form-inputs">
               <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
               <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
               <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
               <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
               <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>

              </div>     
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-actions">
              <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have `devise/shared/registration_items`

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#myModal", :method => 'get' %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

and `_navbar.html.erb`

```
<%= render 'devise/shared/login_items' %>   
<%= render 'devise/shared/registration_items' %>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: 3 questions with same topic.. If you get new problem, you should update your question or tell to answerer on your question you get new problem. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24007284/1297435 http://stackoverflow.com/q/24008841/1297435

Comment: Thanks but when I do that, I get responses from people telling me to create  a new request when I get a new problem. It's actually a different problem each time.

Comment: Please could you reverse your negative markings. I really hope that doesn't dissuade someone from helping with this problem. It's actually really difficult to navigate and I try to be as open and thorough in my research before asking a question as I can be, before tearing my hair out. I hope that sharing my sequence and code helps others with similar issues.

Comment: 2 questions same problem, this question your problem is **"when I click on the navbar link to 'register' - the page refreshes but nothing happens"**, and [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008841/rails-devise-bootstrap-sign-up-modal) is **"when i click on 'Register' in my navbar. Nothing happens"**, where the different of problem on your questions? If your problem is different also include stacktrace.

Comment: Hi Anonymousxxx, no, the same error comes out of a different set of code. You can compare the code posted with each problem and see that it's a different issue. Happy to post further details. Is there something particular that you'd like to see to be able to comment on the possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

This works! The modal and the link to it need to be in the same view file.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#myModal", :method => 'get' %>
    </li>


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Request an invite</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
              <%= f.error_notification %>

              <div class="form-inputs">
                <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
                <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
                <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
                <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
                <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="form-actions">
              <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
            <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



<% end %>
```