# Rails Devise Bootstrap Sign Up modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm trying to alter my devise registration view file to work with bootstrap modals.

I have followed the bootstrap instructions and slotted the form into the modal and linked it to the navbar menu. Now, when i click on 'Register' in my navbar. Nothing happens. The form doesn't go anywhere. I had this working when it was just a standard page view. Can anyone help? Thank you.

I am trying to follow this answer but am getting confused: [Twitter Bootstrap Modal not popping up for user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348877/twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-popping-up-for-user-login)

I have:

views/devise/shared/registration_items:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to 'Register', new_user_registration_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#myModal", :method: 'get' %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

views/devise/registrations/new

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign up</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
           <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
             <%= f.error_notification %>

             <div class="form-inputs">
               <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
               <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
               <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
               <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
               <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>


                  </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-actions">
              <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

I get a syntax error (syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>) on this line:

```
  <%= render 'devise/shared/registration_items' %>
```

Please can anyone help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error. Change to `:method => 'get'` or `method: 'get'` in the line below

```
'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#myModal", :method: 'get'
```